# Using ASP.NET project for online demo using visual studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

Not a programming question. I use a mac. I don't have Visual studio.(Cannot buy ) I want to do a ASP.NET project with SQL Server as backend. How can i do it? This project is for another person to check my code, so they should be able to see my code. Like for a interview.How do i do that? Any information will be helpful. Will visual studio online help me? 
I know this forum is coding only questions forum, but did not know where else I can get good help.

Comment: VS Express Edition is free, but run only on Windows. I think you can use MonoDevelop on mac. And put code on github for review.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio online will help you by giving you a place to put your code where a small number of others can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install Visual studio on Mac operating system in any way.
You can install it on windows operating system only.

So, you can install BootCamp.
BootCamp lets you to install Windows on your Mac.

The disadvantage of this is that you can't run both Mac operating system and Windows operating system in parallel, But you can buy virtual machine software (like: Parallel or VMWare) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) on Mac.

How to show your code: You can use Visual Studio Online as repository if you open mutual account with this guy who wants to see your code. But easy way is to use [GitHub](https://github.com/) (if you don't care about privacy of your code).